# How to create java pojo from table using jooq not by xml?

Tags: java, pojo, jooq

I want to create .java from table using jooq programmaticly not by .xml.

I have already tried by xml but it is not what i want.

Firstly is it possible to do by jooq?

Secondly does anybody know how to do it?

```
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.Record;
import org.jooq.Result;
import org.jooq.SQLDialect;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator;
import org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator;
import org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;

        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

            DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
            Result<Record> result = create.select().from("AUTHOR").fetch();

            //------------ here I want to create AUTHOR.java from table AUTHOR by connecting to database  
            DefaultGenerator  g = new DefaultGenerator();
            MySQLDatabase database = new MySQLDatabase();
            database.getSchema(conn.getSchema());
            JavaGenerator javaGenerator = new JavaGenerator();
            javaGenerator.generate(database);

            //------------

            for (Record r : result) {
                Long id = r.getValue(AUTHOR.ID);
                String firstName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME);
                String lastName = r.getValue(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME);

                System.out.println("ID: " + id + " first name: " + firstName + " last name: " + lastName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can programmatically configure jOOQ's code generator. When you look at [`GenerationTool`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen/src/main/java/org/jooq/util/GenerationTool.java)'s source code, you'll see that you can call its overloaded `main()` method either from the console ([as documented in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/)), or by passing it an `org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration` object. An example:

```
import org.jooq.util.jaxb.*;

// [...]

Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
        .withDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library")
        .withUser("root")
        .withPassword("root"))
    .withGenerator(new Generator()
        .withName("org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator")
        .withDatabase(new Database()
            .withName("org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
            .withIncludes(".*")
            .withExcludes("")
            .withInputSchema("library"))
        .withTarget(new Target()
            .withPackageName("org.jooq.util.maven.example")
            .withDirectory("target/generated-sources/jooq")));

GenerationTool.main(configuration);
```

The above configuration POJOs are generated by XJC, so you can use exactly the same structure as with the XML configuration.

[This is now also documented in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/).